# What’s the best way to upload data with boto3 to Dynamodb, directly or using s3 and data pipelines instead?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I have a JSON file with large size and I would like to know if it is better to upload this information directly to Dynamodb using boto3 or instead it is better to upload this on s3 first and then using data pipeline, upload this to Dynamodb?

Here is a few samples data:

Sample1:

```
{  
   "updated":{  
      "n":"20181226"
   },
   "periodo":{  
      "n":"20180823"
   },
   "tipos":{  
      "m":{  
         "Disponible":{  
            "m":{  
               "total":{  
                  "n":"200"
               },
               "Saldos de Cuentas de Ahorro":{  
                  "n":"300"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mediana_disponible":{  
      "n":"588"
   },
   "mediana_ingreso":{  
      "n":"658"
   },
   "mediana_egreso":{  
      "n":"200"
   },
   "documento":{  
      "s":"2-2"
   }
}
```

For this sample, this is only one record and in average there are 68 millons of records and the file size is 70Gb.

Sample2:

```
{  
   "updated":{  
      "n":"20190121"
   },
   "zonas":{  
      "s":"123"
   },
   "tipo_doc":{  
      "n":"3123"
   },
   "cods_sai":{  
      "s":"3,234234,234234"
   },
   "cods_cb":{  
      "s":"234234,5435,45"
   },
   "cods_atm":{  
      "s":"54,45,345;345,5345,435"
   },
   "num_doc":{  
      "n":"345"
   },
   "cods_mf":{  
      "s":"NNN"
   },
   "cods_pac":{  
      "s":"NNN"
   }
}
```

For this sample, this is only one record and in average there are 7 millons of records and the file size is 10Gb.

Thanks in advance

Comment: More details please. How much data? What type of data? Is the data clean or needs to be processed before storing in DB?

Comment: It’s already clean, the average size is 80GB.

Comment: What is the format of the JSON? Edit your question with the a sample of the data. Try to think ahead of my question with as much information as you can think of.

Comment: HI John, thanks for you help, i hope that there is as much details as you need to help me out with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your situation I would use AWS Data Pipeline to import your Json data files into DynamoDB from S3. There are many examples provided by AWS and by others on the Internet.

Your use case for me is just on the border between simply writing a Python import script and deploying Data Pipeline. Since your data is clean, deploying a pipeline will be very easy.

I would definitely copy your data to S3 first and then process your data from S3. The primary reason is the unreliability of the public Internet for this large of data.

If this task will be repeated over time, the I would definitely use AWS Data Pipeline.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what if we have a dedicated 350 Mb internet channel? Would you still recommend to use S3 and data pipeline instead or uploading this information directly to dynamodb?

Comment: I seldom recommend using any form of public Internet for ETL.

Comment: What's the difference between using S3 in the middle instead of uploading the information directly to dynamodb?

Comment: The primary difference is reliability. Public Internet connections are often very poor for very large data transfers. Most AWS services cannot connect back to private data without specialized networking (VPNs, etc.).

Comment: I don't use public internet I use a dedicated channel to upload this information. Why the reliability issue is only applied for uploading directly to dynamodb and not if i use s3, at the end i'm transfering the same size of data, does not matter if it is to s3 or dynamodb.

Comment: @JuanEstebanCastañoSalazar - Please provide all details when you ask a question. If you keep adding details, the answer may change. Most people do not have dedicated connections to AWS, so I do NOT assume that in my answers. A dedicated AWS connection might change my answer. My suggestion, close this question and ask a new one where you provide all details at the start.

Comment: Here is the new question, hope you can help me out with this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54410828/best-way-to-upload-data-with-boto3-to-dynamodb

Comment: @JuanEstebanCastañoSalazar - Once you close the current question.

Comment: It has been closed.

Comment: did you have the chance to see my new question?