# Best way to upload data with boto3 to DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm using Python boto3 to upload data to AWS.

I have a dedicated connection to AWS of 350 Mbps.

I have a large JSON file and I would like to know if it is better to upload this information directly to DynamoDB or instead it is better to upload this on S3 first and then using data pipeline to upload this to DynamodDB?

My data is already clean and it doesn't need to be processed. I just need to expose this information to DynamoDB in the most efficient and reliable way.

My script will be run on a sever with the following specifications: 
512 GB RAM
48 CPU cores

Here is some sample data:

Sample1:

```
{  
   "updated":{  
      "n":"20181226"
   },
   "periodo":{  
      "n":"20180823"
   },
   "tipos":{  
      "m":{  
         "Disponible":{  
            "m":{  
               "total":{  
                  "n":"200"
               },
               "Saldos de Cuentas de Ahorro":{  
                  "n":"300"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mediana_disponible":{  
      "n":"588"
   },
   "mediana_ingreso":{  
      "n":"658"
   },
   "mediana_egreso":{  
      "n":"200"
   },
   "documento":{  
      "s":"2-2"
   }
}
```

For this sample, this is only one record and on average there are 68 million and the file size is 70GB.

Sample2:

```
{  
   "updated":{  
      "n":"20190121"
   },
   "zonas":{  
      "s":"123"
   },
   "tipo_doc":{  
      "n":"3123"
   },
   "cods_sai":{  
      "s":"3,234234,234234"
   },
   "cods_cb":{  
      "s":"234234,5435,45"
   },
   "cods_atm":{  
      "s":"54,45,345;345,5345,435"
   },
   "num_doc":{  
      "n":"345"
   },
   "cods_mf":{  
      "s":"NNN"
   },
   "cods_pac":{  
      "s":"NNN"
   }
}
```

For this sample, this is only one record and on average there are 7 million records and the file size is 10GB.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The bottlenecks are the network bandwidth and the write capacity configured on your DynamoDB instance. One write capacity unit represents one write per second for an item up to 1kB in size.

You didn't mention any time limits that you have in loading the data. If this is a one-off job and there are no tight windows for comnpleting the upload then I would be inclined to keep the process as simple as possible. Increase the Dynamo write capacity units to whatever you can afford bearing in mind your network bandwidth limits, then run the upload directly from your server.

Comment: Data Pipeline is very unfriendly, it produces almost no useful output. I would definitely go with boto3 script.